# How to plot many barplots using par and pdf and not have them get cut off in R

Tags: r, pdf, plot, par

I have a curious question, I am using par() to make a muli-panel barplot, I am noticing after using xlim and width to make bars across all barplot() the same, I am notice the main ="" not centering on the bars themselves, but the plot. I am also seeing that for some plots, the bars them selves are being cut off.

I was wondering 1) if it is possible to make main"" command in barplot() center over just the bars and 2) How to keep bars from being cut off, but be able to plot each of the plots using the par(mfow="") Any comments would be helpful.

I have this generic example:

```
# create data
a<-c(1:100)
b<-c(1:200)
c<-c(1:300)
d<-c(1:400)
e<-c(1:500)
f<- c(1:600)

#make dataframes for barplots
test<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
test1<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
test2<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
test3<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d,e))
test4<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d,e,f))

#gets means for each column
a1<-colMeans(test)
a2<-colMeans(test1)
a3<-colMeans(test2)
a4<-colMeans(test3)
a5<-colMeans(test4)

#lets plot
pdf(file= "/Users/Highf_000/Desktop/prac1.pdf");
par(mfrow = c(2, 3),     # 2 rows x 4 columns layout
      oma = c(2, 2, 0, 0), # two rows of text at the outer left and bottom margin
      mar = c(5, 5, 2, 1)+0.1, # space for one row of text at ticks and to separate plots
      mgp = c(2, 1, 0),    # axis label at 2 rows distance, tick labels at 1 row
      xpd = NA) 

barplot(mean(a), xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")
barplot(a1, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")
barplot(a2, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")
barplot(a3, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")
barplot(a4, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")
barplot(a5, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.2, main = "Learning")

dev.off()
```

This is my output:

[image: This is my output:]

We see the title isn't centered in the last right plot for sure, and the bottom right two plots are being cut off. How to plots to not cut the bars off and maintain the bar widths across all plots? Take into account my real data will have anywhere from 3 bar in a plot to 20 bars in a plot.

Comment: you're restricting the x-limits to something more narrow than your data--why wouldn't the bars get cut off? your second question is about centering the title based on the number of bars, not the width of the plot? try `bp <- barplot(a2, xlim = c(0, 10)); mtext("Learning", at = mean(bp), font = 2)`

Comment: @ rawr, This is going to be a really dumb question, I understand how xlim works in plot(), but in barplot() xlim seems to behave differently. How do we figure out what the xlim should be? Also if you write up the above answer, I will vote that.

Comment: the limits are calculated within barplot and it depends on not only the number of bars but the width of the bars (which you are changing) and the space between, so it's usually not as simple as having 5 bars and the xlim should be 1-5 or something